# Under which conditions do positive real roots exist in a quadratic of two variables?

Tags: quadratics

Suppose we have a quadratic polynomial equation in two variables:

$$p(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx + ey + f = 0$$

Under which conditions does at least one solution $p(x,y)=0$ exist with $x$ and $y$ both real and positive?

Comment: I know how to answer the question for a quadratic in one variable, so I have tried to reduce this problem to that problem, but so far unsuccessfully.

Comment: Have you tried to study the two variables function $p$ and finding a condition on the parameters so that the minimum and maximum are of different signs?